What does "4, U" mean in VS Code Git?
In the VS Code Git panel
I get a

4, U

colored in red next to the file name.
What does it mean?
Where can I find the list of symbols shown on git pane of VS Code?

Have you tried hovering over it to get the tooltip. The 4 is probably the problem count. Not sure about U though

U is untracked, but just hovering over it should have told you that.

The number and the U are two different things.
The number means the number of detected "problems" (sometimes VS Code is wrong) in this file. U means the file is not tracked in git. Hover ith your mouse for a description.

